# Source Tree - what is the difference between remove, discard, ignore?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I"m new to Sourcetree, so if I right click on a file in the unstaged files area, there are multiple options. So my question is: what is the difference between remove, ignore and discard? Also, when I just do pull from a branch, why do I need to commit unstaged files? I just want to do a pull (update).
And how I can just compare a file with this remote version?
Thank you!

Answer (score 27):

Ignore - ignore this filename/location. File is added to .gitignore.

Discard - discard current unstaged/uncommited changes done in this file.

Remove - removes file from filesystem.

Comment: Ignore - ignore this filename/location. File is added to .gitignore.
                    after I do Ignore it is added to git ignore and then gitIgnore 
                    file is stack in the unstaged Files zone and I cant get rid of it.  
Discard - discard current unstaged/uncommited changes done in this file.
                    are the changes get deleted in my local file?
Remove - removes file from filesystem.              is remove delete the file 
                    from my local?

Comment: Discard = throw away any changes and REVERT to last checked in state. Yes, changes are deleted (There is an option to copy to clipboard)